# bbding package showing wrong results for characters

Tags: fonts

I have a very simple file that I created to just experiment with two characters in `bbding`.  Here it is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{bbding}

\begin{document}
\noindent
Correlation is: \FiveStarOpen \\
Convolution is: \FiveStar
\end{document}
```

This works very well and shows what is to be expected.  Then, I added those in my real document which is about 20 pages long.  In that document, the two characters are shown as `9` and `8`.  I have checked every possibility but unable to figure it out.  The only two packages that I have included are `times` and `courier`; I even tried to comment those out without any change in result.  Can someone see what could be the problem?

I have tried to use this with TeXWorks on a Mac and on Linux; same issue.

Comment: I'm afraid it will be difficult to help without some information about the problem. You need to post an example which can be used to reproduce the issue. Otherwise, all we can probably say is that something is awry in your real document. Or you could look at the console output and/or log file to see what is wrong.

Comment: I have no problem with providing the complete document.  It is available at http://www.cs.umsl.edu/~sanjiv/classes/cs5420/lectures/spatial.tex and the problem is on lines 897 and 899.  The included file `abbr.tex` is also on the same site as http://www.cs.umsl.edu/~sanjiv/classes/cs5420/lectures/abbr.tex

Comment: The instructions for creating a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) will help you to cut the document down to the minimum necessary to reproduce the issue. (This is just a mechanical process and you may even find the problem yourself.)

Comment: One thought: are you sure you are in text mode? You won't get the expected results in maths mode.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion @cfr.  I removed everything and found out that I had the characters in math mode.  I enclosed those in `\mbox{}` and that worked perfect.

Comment: @unxnut In order to close this issue, you may want to delete it as "too localized" or you add a real MWE (showing the problem) and a better title. Then, you may answer your own question in order to help future readers. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the suggestion by @cfr, I created the MWE as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{bbding}

\newcommand{\corr}{\mbox{\FiveStarOpen}}
\newcommand{\conv}{\mbox{\FiveStar}}

\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
\item Correlation is given by
      \[ w(x,y) \corr f(x,y) = \sum_{s=-a}^a \sum_{t=-b}^b w(s,t) f(x+s,y+t) \]
\item Convolution is given by
      \[ w(x,y) \conv f(x,y) \sum_{s=-a}^a \sum_{t=-b}^b w(s,t) f(x-s,y-t) \]
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

I did not have the characters enclosed in `\mbox` which caused the problem.  Now, the problem is fixed.  Thanks for the help; next time I'll remember to create an MWE before venturing to post for help here.